# Is it OK for my domain objects use a factory method, or factory layer, when they need to?

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory

Is it OK for my domain objects to use a factory method, or factory layer, when they need to?

I have been trying to get client code to create and inject dependencies wherever they exist, however it seems that this is not always the right thing to do.  In this question here, for example [Where to check for mandatory properties in a domain object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608239/where-to-check-for-mandatory-properties-in-a-domain-object), a User can own many Pets; and a Pet cannot exist without a User.

I have been trying to create a Pet, then add it to the User's collection, but the problem is that in order to create the Pet I need to supply the User (which defeats the purpose of having a `User::addPet(ConcretePet)` method).

What I would rather do is have a `User::addPet()` method that accepts an array of parameters, then creates the Pet using either a factory or a factory method.  Is this reasonable?

EDIT: Another Scenario

Here's another scenario where I would like my domain model to access a factory.  If my User's need a License object for each Pet they own, wouldn't it make sense to create this in the User::addPet(ConcretePet) method?  Sure I could create the license in the service layer, but again that means taking business logic away from the domain!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a pet cannot exist without it's user, it does not mean a user can exist without pet.

The question is whether the pet needs it's user and vice versa. I can pretty much think about both existing alone, and cross-referencing them might either be a good idea or not, depending on the problem. Generally speaking I'd say it's rather not so good, because it means that the user can interact with the pet, and the pet can interact with the user, and both interactions can trigger reverse interactions, resulting in an endless loop.

A safer solution would be to have an object that contains both user and pet and directs all interactions between them: A user-pet-relationship.

If you state that you cannot inject an objects dependencies, then you are doing something wrong. If you want to inject a factory instead, you are going to use the service locator antipattern, which is another code smell that should be avoided.

> What I would rather do is have a User::addPet() method that accepts an
>   array of parameters, then creates the Pet using either a factory or a
>   factory method. Is this reasonable?

It is not. You do not have any more information inside this function than outside. All the pet parameters do exist, and you have the user object. What else do you need to create a pet with a relationship to the user, and then add that pet to the user?

Comment: Hi Sven, I can create a User without a Pet, no problem.  And when I create the Pet, I can inject the User, no problem.  In fact, I have a service layer that can do all that, no problem.  But that leaves my domain model really anaemic.  I can put an addPet(ConcretePet) method on the User object, but what would it do?  The Pet has already been attached to the User, and there's nothing left to do.

Comment: If there is nothing left to do, then what do you wish to more? Unless there is a reason, you shouldn't be doing more than necessary. But I may still misunderstand your problem.

Comment: Hi Sven, if I let the service layer look after adding a Pet to a User, my domain model starts to look anaemic.  If the domain model is supposed to reflect the real world, I think I need an addPet method on user.  (Otherwise my domain logic is spread across two layers).

Comment: The structure you described probably IS anaemic. You have a user. And a pet that get's the user injected via constructor. And then you add that pet to the user with a function. This completely illustrates that there can be a single user without a pet, but no pet without a user. And both know of each other internally. If you think this is anaemic, then you haven't described enough what you want to do afterwards with these objects.

Comment: Adding a license is basically the same thing. Can a license object exist without a user? Without a pet? And should the user be able to create his own licenses, or should that really be a function of an authority that emits these on request. Yes, you can include a licence factory in the user that creates the license object for any pet that gets attached to the user, but that is not how "reality" works. Either the pet comes with it's own license, or the user comes with the license, but the license must come out of somewhere else on a different layer.

Comment: OK, I think I'm starting to get it...  So, if in reality a license is only issued when a Pet is attached to a User, would I put a call to a Licence Factory in User::addPet()?

Comment: What makes a licensed pet different from one without? Who owns the license? You'd probably want to `User::addPet(LicensedPet)`, which means you need the user, then the license, and can then create the pet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33398/discussion-between-kim-prince-and-sven)